# SQLBuider how to create dynamic query with Talend Open Studio

Tags: postgresql, talend, sqlbuilder

I have data in excel file which I want to insert into database table. One of the column (name) is connected with another table from db. I would like to make a simple query according to value from excel and put into table only id.

Sample of excel file:

```
age       name     position
-------  -------  -------
23        Kate      PWN
36        John      TDF
```

Sample of table from db:

```
id        name     
-------  -------  
1         Kate    
2         John
```

Table which I would like to put data from excel:

```
id       name_id  position
-------  -------  -------
1           1      PWN
2           2      TDF
```

Basically I need to get data from excel file, iterate and make a simple query

```
SELECT (id) FROM name WHERE name = name_from_excel;
```

Then I can put id into proper field in tMap.

[tMap where description and value are name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhgA8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple join in Talend:

```
                DB Input
                    |
                    |  
tFileInputExcel -- tMap -- DB Output
```

Inside tMap you join the column Name from your excel with the Name column from your table, and insert the columns you want in your target DB

Comment: Could you please check my image which I added? I've got a reply that the *id cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: That's normal, you didn't specify what you want to do with the 2 fields you added; for instance, if you want to concatenate them, you should do: field1 + field2

Comment: I do not want to concatenate them. I need to make a query according to field1 and get from db field2. How can I do it?